# How to escape special characters present in xml string in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a XML string coming from Java in base64 encoded format.

```
PHJvb3Q+PGNoaWxkPiY8L2NoaWxkPjxjaGlsZD48PC9jaGlsZD48Y2hpbGQ+PjwvY2hpbGQ+PGNoaWxkPns8L2NoaWxkPjxjaGlsZD59PC9jaGlsZD4vcm9vdD4=
```

I decode it using `xdmp:base64-decode()`. It gives me output as

```
<root><child>&</child><child><</child><child>></child><child>{</child><child>}</child>/root>
```

The output is a string. In order to convert it to XML, I use `xdmp:unquote()`, but the special characters present here produces an error.

I also tried using the `repair-full` option with `xdmp:unquote()`, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Note: I have some special characters present in my actual data those are causing some unwanted errors.

How to handle such type of scenario to insert the XML in MarkLogic?

Comment: That's malformed XML. Are you able to fix the source? Characters like `&`, `<`, `>`, `"`, and `'` should be expressed as entities: `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;`, and `&apos;`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text from that base64 encoded string is not well-formed XML. In addition to the `&` and `<` not being encoded properly, the closing tag for the `root` element is missing `<`. At the end of the string, `</child>/root>` should be `</child></root>`.

As an example of how it might be possible to scrub the text and repair it, the below code will fix up this specific decoded value and then use `xdmp:unquote()` to parse as XML:

```
xdmp:unquote(
 replace(
  replace(
   replace(
     xdmp:base64-decode("PHJvb3Q+PGNoaWxkPiY8L2NoaWxkPjxjaGlsZD48PC9jaGlsZD48Y2hpbGQ+PjwvY2hpbGQ+PGNoaWxkPns8L2NoaWxkPjxjaGlsZD59PC9jaGlsZD4vcm9vdD4=")
   ,"&amp;", "&amp;amp;")
  ,"&gt;&lt;&lt;", "&gt;&amp;lt;&lt;")
 ,"/root>", "&lt;/root>")
)
```

It produces the following well-formed XML:

```
<root>
  <child>&</child>
  <child><</child>
  <child>></child>
  <child>{</child>
  <child>}</child>
</root>
```

However, this sort of repair is tedious and can become difficult. It is probably best to use tools such as [[image: TagSoup] TagSoup](http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) to repair the markup and turn it into well-formed XML.